# MVC 3 Dropdowns & Multiple Model ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm pretty new to MVC, but I'm trying to set up a two step user registration system.  I have an register model and several other models in a viewmodel called Registration.  A user will have a profile based on the register model and then they will select a Producer/Distributor/Restaurant/Importer that they are part of, or create a new one of those.  My ViewModel that is returned doesn't validate or pickup the values in my dropdownlists.  They populate correctly, but on the post they aren't in the vm.  Below is my view/controller/and models.  I've been searching the net for 2 days with no luck.  Also, if you think my method of registration is wacky, let me know.  Thanks!

controller:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private vfContext db = new vfContext();
    //
    // GET: /Registration/

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.UserTypeID = new SelectList(db.UserTypes, "UserTypeID", "Name");
        ViewBag.ProducerID = new SelectList(db.Producers, "ProducerID", "Name");
        ViewBag.PublicationID = new SelectList(db.Publications, "PublicationID", "Name");
        ViewBag.ImporterID = new SelectList(db.Importers, "ImporterID", "Name");
        ViewBag.DistributorID = new SelectList(db.Distributors, "DistributorID", "Name");
        ViewBag.RestaurantID = new SelectList(db.Restaurants, "RestaurantID", "Name");

        RegistrationViewModel reg = new RegistrationViewModel();

        ViewData.Model = reg;

        return View("Registration");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegistrationViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            //email is userid
            Membership.CreateUser(vm.Register.Email, vm.Register.Password, vm.Register.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Profile current = Profile.GetProfile(vm.Register.Email);
                current.FirstName = vm.Register.FirstName;
                current.LastName = vm.Register.LastName;
                current.Address1 = vm.Register.Address1;
                current.Address2 = vm.Register.Address2;
                current.City = vm.Register.City;
                current.State = vm.Register.State;
                current.Postal = vm.Register.Postal;
                current.UserTypeID = vm.Register.UserTypeID;
```

view - i'm having a hard time copying it over, so the issue is with ddls, so here is how I have the user type id one done

```
@model vf2.Models.RegistrationViewModel
                <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Register.UserTypeID, "User Type")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserTypeID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.UserTypeID)
            </div>
```

Models:

```
 public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }
    public Producer Producer { get; set; }
    public Distributor Distributor { get; set; }
    //public Publication Publication { get; set; }
    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
    public Importer Importer { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my register model.

```
    public class RegisterModel
{
    //[Required]
    //[Display(Name = "User name")]
    //public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address Cont.")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postal { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int ProducerID { get; set; }
    public int DistributorID { get; set; }
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public int ImporterID { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantID { get; set; }

    public virtual Producer Producer{ get; set; }
    public virtual Distributor Distributor { get; set; }
    public virtual Publication Publication { get; set; }
    public virtual Importer Importer { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

producer model:

```
    public class Producer
{
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Postal { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wines { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out by adding a the following to my viewmodel:

```
        public IEnumerable<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
```

and then this to my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Register.UserTypeID,new SelectList(Model.UserTypes,"UserTypeID","Name"),"Select account type")
```